# Building a VISIO addin to show relevent data on shape selection by creating rectangle and include text in it

Tags: add-in, visio, office-addins

```
Visio.Page visioPage = this.Application.ActivePage;
//Create a rectangle
Visio.Shape details = visioPage.DrawRectangle(45, 45, 45, 45);
Visio.Selection selection = Window.Selection;
            foreach (dynamic item in selection)
            {
                Visio.Shape shp = item as Visio.Shape;
                if (shp != null)
                {  
                   //Dropping Rectangle on to the page
                   visioPage.Drop(details, 50, 50);
                }
 }
```

Trying above code to create an rectangle on a visio inside Application_SelectionChanged Event. However,Not able to see rectangle on Visio. Please point out mistake here or any pointers regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rectangles appear to have zero width and height. May this be the reason?
DrawRectangle accepts x1, y1, x2, y2 coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Was Missing VisioStencil.

```
 Visio.Documents visioDocs = this.Application.Documents;
    // Get Basic Shapes Stencil
     Visio.Document visioStencil = visioDocs.OpenEx("Basic Shapes.vss",
                (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
    //Get Rectangle Shape
    Visio.Master visioRectMaster = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Rectangle");
    // Add Shape to Page
    Visio.Shape visioRectShape = visioPage.Drop(visioRectMaster, rectX, rectY);
    visioRectShape.NameU = "ShapeName";
```